# the dreaded UTF-8 BOM

Tags: php

I read your answer to reformat php files used by includes and it did remove the problem.  My question is we are working on a web site that needs to display different laguages, will this be a problem?

Thanks Conrad

Comment: What answer are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

The BOM is not necessary in UTF-8. It can be safely removed from your PHP scripts without losing UTF-8 support.

Comment: The UTF-8 BOM can be used to detect the encoding. But as long as the character encoding is properly declared otherwise, it can be safely removed.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP treats all input as latin-1, and therefore treats the BOM as latin-1 characters that should be output to the browser. UTF-8 in PHP "works" because it's possible to write PHP as a channel that serves the UTF-8 bytes as-is.